# Envio Objeto con Arrray en Ajex Asp.Net Core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Tengo un problema, estoy enviando un objeto en json que dentro tienen Array de int al controller de asp.net core pero me vienen a null, que le pasa al código.

Pero no soy capaz de recuperar los datos en el controllador, ¿que es lo que me esta pasando?

gracias

```
 function btnClickRecalcular(e)
    {
        var idConvenioLaborals = [1, 2, 4]; 
        var idLocations = [1, 2, 4];             

        var obj = {
                IdGrupoConvenioLaborals: idConvenioLaborals,
                IdGrupoLocations: idLocations,                   
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ calcular: obj }), 
            url: '/Home/Calcular',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result === false) {
                      we paint the result in the field -> NumEmployee
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Y el Controller

```
 public class CalcularVM
    {
        public int[] IdGrupoConvenioLaborals { get; set; }
        public int[] IdGrupoLocations { get; set; }
   }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Calcular(CalcularVM calcular)
    {
        // we perform calculations with the parameters we receive
        int total = 1425;
        return Json(total);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambiando y adeas hay que meter en el controller

pero hay que poner en ASP.Net Core esto -> [FromBody]

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Calcular([FromBody]CalcularVM calcular)
    {
        // we perform calculations with the parameters we receive
        int total = 1425;
        return Json(total);
    }
```